# Jet showplan.out shows double output for one query

Tags: ms-access, vb6, jet

I have a recordset in a VB6 project that get's populated from MS Access.
To understand the mechanics of the JET SQL Engine I turned the SHOWPLAN to ON. 
What I see in the showplan.out output file is

> `--temp query--`
>
> `- Inputs to Query -`
>     [some tables and all the indexes + the counts]
>
> `- End inputs to Query -`
>     [the query break-down]

When I execute the query (`rst.Open "SELECT ...", cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockUnspecified`) it shows up **twice** in the showplan.out file. Is this normal? Does it mean Access needs to provide the data twice?

Comment: Is the first one left over from a prior run with showplan? Each run concatenates or adds on to what exists in the file.

Comment: No, it's not left over, it's systematic. I'm not sure if it's an error/feature of the showplan.out logging or that it effectively is executing all queries twice.